# Setting tag on imageview mono for android C#

Tags: android, tags, imageview, xamarin.android

I'm trying to add a tag to a imageview for comparison reasons. But unfortunately, I'm getting an illegal argument exception. The exception takes place on my code when trying to add the tag. Here's how I do it.

```
mainImage.SetTag(1, "circle");
```

Am I doing it wrong? It seems pretty simple, a key and and object value. I thought of using content description value, but mono doesn't seem to support getting content descriptions. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid conflicts, you have to use a known Resource Id for the Tag - you can't just pick your own value.

Try adding an AndroidResource XML file in Resources/Values with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <item type="id" name="MyUniqueTag"/>
</resources>
```

then you should be able to use

```
 mainImage.SetTag(Resource.Id.MyUniqueTag, "circle");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it, but I chose to do something more simple. I created a string for an imageview and store the data that will be compared in a corresponding imageview. Thanks!